# How do I best manage my health and damage boosts during construction?

Tags: robocraft-infinity

As you build your robot in *Robocraft Infinity*, there is a stat panel that shows your health, speed, and damage. There are also health, speed, and damage *boosts* that serve as balances for lacking in the another stat (e.g. less CPU means higher damage boost). **What affects these boosts, specifically?**

The [best explanation i could find](https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2018/01/22/robocraft-infinity-getting-started-preview-xbox-one-windows-10/) is pasted below,  which seems reliable but possibly superficial (it doesn't mention that adding legs increases health boost to a certain point, which is something I noticed):

> When in build mode keep an eye on the Robot info Panel. This will give
>   you a great idea of how your robot will perform in battle. The Damage
>   boost stats is determined by the CPU value of your robot, the health
>   boost stat is determined by the number of actual health cubes and the
>   speed boost is determined by your movement type or the number of
>   thrusters on your robot.

Speed makes sense, and I've noticed smaller bots with one or two big guns seems to do a lot of damage, which also makes sense, since the extra CPU is converted into a damage boost. However, large bots with many small guns, or a single large, seem to still do a lot of damage. It seems like anything near 3000 (max) CPU should be tough, with med/low damage, even if the CPU was spent mostly on weapons.

What affects these boosts, and is there some sort of threshold / sweet spot where boosts are optimally balanced between health, damage, and speed? Maybe through a clever use of certain parts?

Answer (score 2):

Here what I know:

When you add more weapons of the same type your fire rate increases, which thereby increases both damage and drain per second. The firing rate boost is capped at a certain point for each weapon, im not entirely sure but some may not get a fire rate boost when theres multiple though I believe they all do at least a little. Your "Sweet Spot" is where you want it to be. If you prefer burst damage, add more guns until you seem to hit the fire rate cap. If you prefer lower damaged sustain, keep your gun count low. If you want high damage AND sustain, build a small robot with a big damage boost and only a couple low energy draw weapons. As for speed, work it in where you want. Its really a rock paper scissors type deal where as you add more of one your potential for the other two slowly decreases.